# Unsual processing of rewriterule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website file structure is as follows

```
/application
/public
      defaultfile.php
      /static
.htaccess
```

.htaccess contains:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/defaultfile-Copy.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

defaultfile.php contains:

```
<?php echo $_GET['url'];?>
```

When I request for a random url like "/blah/blah/1234", it is rewritten to public/defaultfile.php?url=public/blah/blah/1234.Works fine!

But when the request is for something like "/static/blah/blah" (Please note that static is a subdirectory in public directory),it is rewritten to public/defaultfile.php?url=**public/static/blah/blah/blah/blah**

I cant understand where did that **extra "blah/blah"** came from? I just want to know A STEP-BY-STEP answer for this one and not a way to avoid this.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first rule, exactly?

Comment: To rewrite everything to public directory

Comment: Well, I can't figure it out either. I mirrored your setup and used the tracer to see what may be going wrong, but I don't know why it duplicates the end bit. My trace results are here, where the 6th line seems to be where the problem is: http://hastebin.com/raw/konatababe (I've stripped out a lot of stuff pertaining to my setup, for security reasons. And lol, that URL is weird.)